# Store Multiple Temporary Data in c# Arduino

Tags: c#

I am new in c#, I have a form that receive "+:0" from some machine by ethernet in LAN using arduino, 
the "0" will increase if the same machine send "+" again.
Each pc will randomly send "+" to the form.
the problem is, if the machine A has reached "+:5" and the machine B has just started to send the data("+:0"),
how do I store the temporary data (not stored to database, just in c#) for machine A to proccess the machine B until 
the machine A is called back again? Is there any way to do it?

This is my code to get data from IP:

The `downloadedString`will accept `"+:0"` if the machine send the first data.

```
 public AndonForm()
 {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Interval = (500) * (1); 
        _timer.Enabled = true;        
        _timer.Start();
        _timer.Tick += (timerTick); 
  }


    private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDataFromArduino("http://192.168.1.200/");
        GetDataFromArduino("http://192.168.1.12/");
        GetDataFromArduino("http://192.168.1.166/");
        GetDataFromArduino("http://192.168.1.6/");
    }

    private void GetDataFromArduino(string ipAddress)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        String downloadedString = client.DownloadString(ipAddress);

        if (downloadedString.Contains("SPP"))
        {
            downloadedString = downloadedString.Split(new[] { "<html>\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            tempDownloadString = downloadedString.Substring(0, downloadedString.IndexOf(":"));

            tempCount = downloadedString.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

        }
        else if (downloadedString.Contains("NPK"))
        {
            downloadedString = downloadedString.Split(new[] {"<html>\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            tempDownloadString = downloadedString.Substring(0, downloadedString.IndexOf(":"));

            tempCount = downloadedString.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            tempCount = tempCount.Substring(0, tempCount.IndexOf("<"));
        }
        else
        {
            downloadedString = downloadedString.Split(new[] {"<html>\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            tempDownloadString = downloadedString.Substring(0, downloadedString.IndexOf(":"));


            tempCount = downloadedString.Split(new[] {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            tempCount = tempCount.Substring(0, tempCount.IndexOf("<"));

        }

        if (SPP != null && NPK == null)
        {
            finalDownloadString = tempDownloadString;
            si_DataReceived(tempDownloadString);
            x = tempCount;
        }
        else if (SPP != null && NPK !=null)
        {

            if (x != tempCount || tempDownloadString != finalDownloadString)
            {
                si_DataReceived(tempDownloadString);
                finalDownloadString = tempDownloadString;
                x = tempCount;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            finalDownloadString = tempDownloadString;
            si_DataReceived(tempDownloadString);
            x = tempCount;  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. In your `Dictionary` the key string should be the ip in `ipAddress` variable and `List<string>` are all data send by Arduino for the specific ip.